# How to create std::tuple of subtypes from std::tuple of given typelist

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic, typelist

I have a typelist in form of std::tuple

```
struct A { struct data_type {}; };
struct B { struct data_type {}; };
struct C { struct data_type {}; };
struct D { struct data_type {}; };
//etc

using my_typelist = std::tuple<A, B, C, D>;
```

And I what define variable of tuple, containing inner types. Something like this

```
std::tuple<A::data_type, B::data_type, C::data_type, D::data_type> data;
```

But straightforward solution does not work (https://ideone.com/c8a2FE):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

struct A { using data_type = int; };
struct B { using data_type = char; };

// error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type
template < typename... Ts >
using cvt_2_data = std::tuple< Ts::data... >; 

void main()
{
    using my_typelist = std::tuple<A, B>;
    cvt_2_data<my_typelist> data;
    std::cout 
        << std::get<A::data_type>(data) << " "
        << std::get<B::data_type>(data) << std::endl;
}
```

I've also tried this, and more complicated approaches, but no such luck

```
std::tuple< (Ts::data)... >;
std::tuple< decltype(Ts)::data... >;
```

By the way, I need solution for C++17

Comment: `typename Ts::data...`

Comment: yes, "typename Ts::data..." is important, but its not enough

Answer (score 3):

It seems you want to specify `std::tuple<A, B>` as template argument, and get the type `std::tuple<A::data_type, B::data_type>`. You can do it with helper template and specialization. E.g.

```
template < typename... Ts >
struct cvt_2_data_struct; 
template < typename... Ts >
struct cvt_2_data_struct<std::tuple<Ts...>> {
    using type = std::tuple< typename Ts::data_type... >; 
};

template < typename... Ts >
using cvt_2_data = typename cvt_2_data_struct<Ts...>::type;
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0c9QvQ33N00GPJNg)

BTW: Note the usage of [`typename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename) in `typename Ts::data_type...` and `typename cvt_2_data_struct<Ts...>::type`, it's used to tell that the dependent qualified name is type. See [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/3309790).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Where can I read about why your approach works and my not? I mean except c++ standard.

Comment: @RedApe Your question is special, asking here is a good idea. For documents you can explore on cppreference.com. If you want to read a book, refer to [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/3309790).

Answer (score 2):

Try using partial specialization of a class/struct template:

```
template < typename T >
struct cvt_2_data_struct {};
template < typename... Ts >
struct cvt_2_data_struct<std::tuple< Ts... >> {
    using type = std::tuple< typename Ts::data_type... >;
};

template < typename T >
using cvt_2_data = typename cvt_2_data_struct<T>::type;
```